# Add Calculated Column in Admin Product List

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute

currently i can't find an answer and hope someone can guide and help me to solve my problem.

In the shop i support the qty of a product are packages of items.
We have added a field to the product in which one can save the amount of items inside one package.

My problem is that i have to add a column to the product list containing the total items

eg: qty * items

Would nice if someone has an idea, does't have to be a complete solution, but would be nice if it is :)

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a Solution:

In: *COMPANY/MODULE/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="product_columns" class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <column name="gn_amount" class="COMPANY\MODULE\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Amount">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Menge Stück</item>
                    <item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">77</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">false</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**The Example below uses a custom attribute, so take care while copying**
And than In: *COMPANY/MODULE/Ui/Component/Listing/Columns/Amount.php*

```
<?php
namespace COMPANY\MODULE\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns;
class Amount extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column {

    const NAME = 'column.amount';

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource) {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $packaging_quantity = 0;
                $qty = 1;
                if (isset($item['packaging_quantity'])) {
                    $packaging_quantity = (int) $item['packaging_quantity'];
                }
                if (isset($item['qty'])) {
                    $qty = (int) $item['qty'];
                }
                $item['amount'] = $packaging_quantity * $qty;
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
?>
```